# Merge two Observables into one Observable of the same type

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two Observables of the same type that I want to merge into one observable and remove duplicates.

By now I tried basically all rxjs operators but none of them do what I need. See the attached picture: a lot of the rxjs operators change the type of the resulting observable.
[image]

```
const a: Observable<Foo[]> = ...
const b: Observable<Foo[]> = ...
```

These are my two calls to retrieve some data.

Now the two operations that came the closest:

```
combineLatest(a, b);
```

This one makes a new array with two indexes and the results of a will go in index 0 and results of b will go into index 1. I cant use it like this.

```
const c = a.pipe(mergeMap(a1 => b.pipe(map(a2 => [...a1, ...a2]))));
```

This one nearly got it. The problem here is following:
Lets assume a return 2 results (example value: 1 and 2) and b return also 2 results (example value: 2 and 3). So the "2" is a duplicate, which should not appear twice in the resulting observable.

Does anyone know a combination of the operators so I can combine both observables and remove the duplicates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your observables are http calls, I assume they complete after emitting. you can use forkJoin to combine them:

```
const combine= forkJoin(a, b).pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => a.concat(b))
);
```

if your observables do not complete, use combineLatest:

```
const combine= combineLatest(a, b).pipe(
    map(([a, b]) => a.concat(b))
);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use **zip** to achieve this.

**`import { zip } from 'rxjs';`**

```
let age$ = of<number>(27, 25, 29);
let name$ = of<string>('Foo', 'Bar', 'Beer');
let isDev$ = of<boolean>(true, true, false);

zip(age$, name$, isDev$).pipe(
  map(([age, name, isDev]) => ({ age, name, isDev })),
)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

**`stackblitz`** example:  **https://stackblitz.com/edit/ued3me?file=index.ts**

Comment: 100 examples haven't worked before I tried this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your Observables are not **hot**, eg. they will not push multiple values and will emit one array and complete, this should work:

```
combineLatest(a, b).pipe(
  map(([a, b]) => {
    const filtered = a.filter(i => !b.includes(i));
    return [...filtered, b];
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact needs. For example, removing duplicates is way easier if you only mean sequential duplicates (i.e. "AAA" should become "A", but "ABA" is fine). If you want *only* unique values, I think you need `scan` with some deduplicating logic. And are they emitting objects, or primitives?

In the simplest case, this will do:

```
merge(a, b).pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
```

Or, with removing all duplicates:

```
const deduplicate = arr => [...new Set(arr)];

merge(a, b).pipe(scan(
  (acc, curr) => deduplicate([...acc, curr]), []
)).subscribe(/* ... */);
```

(It'll get a little trickier with objects).

Here's a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a97ag7?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100